# Configure IIS 8.5 to have one log file per application

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, iis-8.5, logparser

Hope everyone is doing great.

**Problem Statement:**

- We want to log (W3C log format) for each application inside 'Default
  Web Site' in a ***separate log file***.

**Additional Info.** :

- Each application inside the 'Default Web Site' is having a dedicated
  application pool of its own
- We are using different versions of IIS (IIS 7.5 and later)

Please refer the blow image of the structure

[image]

Thanks for your all help and support.

Comment: Impossible. Logging is per site.

Comment: @LexLi : Thanks, let say if each application under default web site is configured to use its own app pool -- is there a way to log for individual app pools in separate files?

Comment: Nope. As @LexLi said logging is per site and not per app pool. You could use a software like logparser lizard to get separate out the logs. That would be my route.

Comment: @MuqeetKhan : Thanks, I am using logparser for the same